# Magento: Confusion with Recurring Profiles and Authorize.net ARB or CIM

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, authorize.net, billing, recurring

The next big topic in my new start-up company is recurring billing inside Magento. We will have a few recurring products we'd like to offer alongside some standard one-time products. I've researched the best gateways and so far we think either ARB or CIM from Authorize.net is the way to go.

Some questions come up though such as:

1. If Authorize.net is going to handle the recurring aspect, what is the point of Magento's built-in recurring profiles system? As far as I can tell it's to integrate with the 3rd party by actually taking the user to the 3rd party site? Using Authorize.net would eliminate the need for recurring profiles right?
2. Are we limited to purchasing one of two or three $300 modules out there to get started with **ARB** or **CIM**? So far Magento only supports **SIM** or **DPM**. Or do I have to sit down and extend the built-in Authorize.net payment method? Basically I am trying to say we are on a start-up budget and $300 is a killer at this moment.
3. If we went with **ARB** over **CIM** that means if a customer came back to purchase a second item later on that they would have to re-enter their information (CC #, exp. date, etc.) whereas **CIM** would have this ready to go...is that the correct explanation?
4. We need the flexibility to create unique payment schedules during checkout. For example: We will sell a custom website and hosting package. We want to charge the user 50% of the website cost upfront and 50% upon completion and setup a recurring payment for the hosting package **all at time of checkout**.
5. Along with question #4, currently Magento's recurring profiles limit nominal items to be purchased separately than regular products. This is not acceptable for us and a customer **must be able to purchase all wanted items together in one checkout page**.

Sorry for this lengthy post but I'm very curious to see what our options might be given all we want/need to do. Any advise is good advice!

Comment: For anyone else facing this choice, I would suggest using CIM over ARB. There are some very annoying idiosyncrasies in how ARB is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Magento recurring billing code allows customers to view and edit their subscription inside the Magento webstore, so there's no redirection to third party.
2. Short answer: yes, or roll your own.
3. I believe that is the case, but you need to check with Authorize.Net on that.
4. Not sure what the question is here?
5. Then refer to your earlier question on this topic that I answered. You can choose to override the core functionality, but you need to familiarize yourself with the reasons why Magento chose to enforce that restriction. I believe that is likely due to a restriction in the Paypal interface, and other recurring billing gateways such as Authorize.Net may be able to cope with one-off and recurring items in the same transaction.

HTH,
JD

Comment: Thanks for the info. We have actually ditched the extension path for obvious reasons and are pursuing subscription systems that hook into the checkout process.

Comment: Good luck, please let us know how it goes.

Comment: Any solution yet?